# Visualizing halo orbits

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, james-webb-telescope, python, halo-orbit

I'd like to visualize JWST's orbit (or any halo orbit that resembles it) preferably in Python. Does anyone have any code or resource I could read? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57832/38535 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49616/16685 My code is Sage, which is built on Python.

Comment: No code, but insights from an an analogue dude https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57644/jwst-halo-orbits-for-dummies-can-halo-orbits-be-usefully-approximated-by-simple